# Different values in debugger and cell

Tags: excel, vba, function, csv

Below is the code for setting up my function in one of the cells in a csv file.

When I check the debugger it correctly shows my variable value as 2886 but when the variable resolves in the cell it shows the value 5776 (double).

```vb
Dim lRow, asLastrow, amLastrow, bsRow, bmRow As Integer

Sheets("Multiple").Activate
lRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

bmRow = lRow + 1
bsRow = lRow + 1

Sheets("Multiple").Activate
amLastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("Single").Activate
asLastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If asLastrow > 1 Then
    Do While bsRow < asLastrow
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & CStr(bsRow)).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(R[" & CInt(bsRow) & "]C[5],category.csv!C[1]:C[2],2,0),VLOOKUP(R[" & CInt(bsRow) & "]C[6],genre.csv!C[1]:C[2],2,0),INDEX(source.csv!C,MATCH(R[" & CInt(bsRow) & "]C[4],source.csv!C[1],0)))"
        bsRow = bsRow + 1
    Loop
End If
```

Cell contents when I check:

```
=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(F5772,category.csv!B:C,2,0),VLOOKUP(G5772,genre.csv!B:C,2,0),INDEX(source.csv!A:A,MATCH(E5772,source.csv!B:B,0)))
```

Comment: It would help if you provided the debugger and the worksheet values for each of the 3 concatenated elements. In other words, what is the value of only `VLOOKUP(F5772,category.csv!B:C,2,0)` and the other two parts. My guess is just doing this will isolate the problem and you may not need any more help.

Comment: Hi Exactabox, I don't think this error depends on the value of the cell. It is more on the fact that the variable value in the normal excel vba debugger (through F8 stepping into the function) gives a different value and the one which gets picked up in the actual cell is different.
I have some hidden rows at the top of the excel which I don't think is causing the problem because even the cells being looped are giving digits with a different of 2 which suggests that the variable value is doubling

Comment: would you load some example of workbooks involved? (the one with sheets Multiple and Single, genre.csv, source.csv and category.csv)

Comment: Hi,
These are not different workbooks but worksheets from the same workbook. These are just being referenced.

Comment: so what `category.csv!` (and the likes) would refer to?

Comment: It is actually a lookup sheet in the same workbook where I match the name (the name which is not referred correctly because of the incorrect variable value) and then fetch the corresponding code back into the concatenate function

Comment: It would help me to have you post a sample of "not working" sheets

Comment: I'm sorry but there are no not working sheets. Just this piece of code where bsRow shows value of 2886 in the code but when I check the excel sheet which I'm filling up through this code shows the value of bsRow as 5776 (double) as a result the formula never gives me any value because if is looking at the wrong cell.

The sheets are all fine. Please let me know if you still want to see the sheets because they are simply lookup values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R[2886]C[5]` is relative coordinate - 2886 rows below and 5 columns to the right of the cell containing formula.

`R[0]C[5]` or simply `RC[5]` are two correct ways to reference the same row.

Another option is to use absolute coordinates: `R2886C6`.

Comment: Perfect..that's what I was missing. Thanks